# Why is the Netflix live chat option not always available?

Tags: netflix

I am trying to contact Netflix via live chat-- [Netflix live chat support is now legendary](http://happyplace.someecards.com/netflix/netflix-customer-support-offers-perfect-dating-advice/), but for some reason, the live chat option is not available at the [help page](https://help.netflix.com/help).

The help page behavior is the same regardless of whether I am logging into my account, or not; regardless of whether I am using Chrome or Firefox.

[image: No live chat]

My experience is confirmed by [at least one redditor](http://www.reddit.com/r/netflix/comments/214cms/how_do_i_do_a_live_customer_service_text_chat/cg9jr2i).

> I am in the U.S. Just to help, here's what [my page looked like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMSNd.png). Also,
>   the hyperlink did not work. What the hell, Netflix?

[A user does report](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69374/260) that the live chat option is available for him, though.

Why is the Netflix live chat option not always available? What is the real problem?

Answer (score 2):

I went to the help page link that you posted, and there is a link for the live chat at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

Comment: So weird! Why is it that my help page doesn't have it? See updated question

Comment: @Graviton I am in the U.S. too.  I would recommend that you either delete all your browser's cookies and revisit the page, or try going to the page in a different browser.  I am using Chrome.

Comment: I tested on chrome and firefox, same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: LOG OUT. 
If you have a Netflix account with DVD Rentals and are logged in, the bottom of the screen will always read "Chat not available." This is true even if you also have the streaming option.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. Unlike the OP, a chat option *did* appear next to the phone option. However, it said that chat was unavailable and continued to say this for several days at all hours. The user "nobody" is right - just log out of your account, then go to the bottom of the page where it says "Help Center" (underneath "Get Help"); click on that and you should see a chat option. I was then asked whether I was a Netflix member or not. First I said yes, and I was once again directed to a page saying that chat was unavailable. Then I tried again, this time saying that I was not a member, and it worked! I asked the Netflix employee about the problem, and he said that chat should have been available, but that there was some sort of bug. So if this is ever a problem for anyone else, just try logging out and saying that you are not a member.

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought I was doomed when I got this after logging out: https://imgur.com/aPmW0aN